# How to skip a directory that matches a pattern in bash

Tags: bash

```
string="*test"
for dir in $ALIGN_DIR/*/; do 
   if [[ -d $dir && $dir == "$string" ]]; then
       continue
   fi
done
```

This does not work for example $dir = '\home\something\test' does not match the $string and is not skipped.

Comment: Just drop the quotes from `"$string"` in the test.  The quotes mean that all characters in `string`, including `*`, are matched literally.  You'll also need to set the value of `string` to `'*test/'` because `dir` always ends with a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex in your check. Equality of strings won't work with wildcard * by default

```
string=".*test"
for dir in $ALIGN_DIR/*/; do 
   if [[ -d $dir && $dir =~ "$string" ]]; then
       continue
   fi
done
```